# Site Self-Evaluation Review History interface is incomplete

Tags: bug, site-evaluation, review-history

Looking through the Site Self-Evaluation Review History interfaces, the names of reviewers and their review aren't shown for reviews.

For example, [this completed review](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval/9040) on Movies & TV:

[image: Image of completed review]

Compare this to [a completed close review](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/close/14557):

[image: Image of completed close vote]

Obviously, people with the [Access to Moderator Tools](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege can see what votes were cast anyway, so this wouldn't be giving out more information than is already available.

The same is also true of review tasks which are incomplete (you have reviewed but still requires more users to review it), in which it will only show your vote, and not any others cast on the same post.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with this. I frequently see review tasks left off blank, most of the times I just twitch a few times and move on.

Comment: Though in the case of incomplete reviews I guess not showing other people's opinions might help to prevent some kind of influence on your own.

Comment: @ChristianRau I'll clarify that, by incomplete I meant 'Items I have reviewed but still need reviews from other users'.

Comment: As this specific queue no longer exists I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

We don't show the results of these reviews because there could potentially be a *lot* of them. It's fine when there are 3-5 reviewers, but once you start getting into 10+, it's just a lot of noise and the UI isn't really built for that.

Having said that, I agree that a bit more information there would be nice. I'll see about putting up a result summary in the review task.

Comment: A summary could work. Instead of listing the names then their review next to it, maybe list the review then the names of people who voted for that option so it would only be 4 lines maximum?

Comment: @MrLore Not guaranteed to be really space-saving... Again, these could have a lot of responses. I'll see what I can do/what looks best.